# how is the url to a lightning component generated?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Can anyone tell me how is the lightning component url in the browser generated ? It is composed from what ?

e.g this url : /one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJjOkxDMjhfR2VzdGlvbkNvbXB0ZSIsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXMiOnt9LCJ0IjoxNDc5MzY5MTMyOTQ0fQ%3D%3D

I Have notice that the cwODk4OTEy part of the url different for another user. I need to compose this url toward my component for a simple reason that a visualforce page cannot redirect to a component, but i can rewrite my browser url so that it takes me to my component. This work, butI need a way to generate or to calculate this value to the component. Does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The portion of the URL after the # character is a URL encoded, base64 encoded JSON object. If you decode this you end up with the following:

```
  {
    "componentDef" : "c:LC28_GestionCompte",
    "attributes" : {},
    "t" : 1479369132944
  }
```

This is very similar to parameters for the `force:navigateToComponent` event that was added in Winter '17 (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm)

The `t` attribute on the object appears to be a timestamp.

**The internals of this URL are subject to change, so you should really be using one of the supported Lightning events to perform navigation rather than URL hacking.**

Comment: This is the answer i needed :) In fact if i remove the timestamp it still works.