# How to decrypt the lighting url

Tags: lightning

Is there any possibility to decrypt kind of **"..lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZ.."** URL? In classic we know that we can get url parameters and component name in the url, but in the lighting we can't see those. Really appreciate if you can share your thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149098/how-is-the-url-to-a-lightning-component-generated/149106#149106

Comment: Thanks @Kasper, this is the exact thing I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Kasper's comment I decoded the encrypted url from https://www.base64decode.org/  and got the component + parameters